# Group array if found different value in the last type

Tags: javascript

How to split array based on different value on the last group ?
My first approach is by using array.prototype.reduce(). However I still can't make it.

```
const arr = [
  { type: "orange", title: "First" },
  { type: "orange", title: "Second" },
  { type: "banana", title: "Third" },
  { type: "banana", title: "Fourth" },
  { type: "orange", title: "Fifth" },
  { type: "orange", title: "Sixth" }
];
```

My first approach :

```
const result = arr.reduce((prev, curr, i) => {
  if (!prev[curr.type]) {
    prev[curr.type] = [];
  }
  prev[curr.type].push(curr);
  return prev;
}, {});
```

expect:

```
[
[ { type: "orange", title: "First" },
  { type: "orange", title: "Second" }
],
[
 { type: "banana", title: "Third" },
 { type: "banana", title: "Fourth" }
], 
[ { type: "orange", title: "Fifth" },
  { type: "orange", title: "Sixth" }
]
]
```

Comment: Your expected output is invalid. An object cannot have duplicate keys.

Comment: Thanks, well. I have update my expected output.

Answer (score 1):

In your reducer function, simply check whether the last item in the accumulator array has the same type, and if so, push the current item to it. Otherwise, push a new array to the accumulator.

```js
const arr=[{type:"orange",title:"First"},{type:"orange",title:"Second"},{type:"banana",title:"Third"},{type:"banana",title:"Fourth"},{type:"orange",title:"Fifth"},{type:"orange",title:"Sixth"}];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => (acc[acc.length - 1]?.[0].type != curr.type ? acc.push([curr]) : acc[acc.length - 1].push(curr), acc), [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution for you required problem. When type value coming same in serial wise then it make a group according to above problem.

```js
const arr = [
  { type: "orange", title: "First" },
  { type: "orange", title: "Second" },
  { type: "banana", title: "Third" },
  { type: "banana", title: "Fourth" },
  { type: "orange", title: "Fifth" },
  { type: "orange", title: "Sixth" }
];

function makeGroup(arr){
    const result = arr.reduce((acc,curr, idx) => {
        if(idx === 0){
            acc[0] = [curr];
        }
        else if(idx>0 && acc[idx-1] && acc[idx-1][0].type === curr.type){
            acc[idx-1] = [...acc[idx-1],curr];
        }
        else{
            acc[idx] = [curr];
        }
        return acc;
    },[]);
    
    let groupArray = result.filter((item)=>item);
    return groupArray;
}
let groupArray = makeGroup(arr)

console.log(groupArray);
```